# Coordinating emission and subscription in Kotlin coroutines with hot flows

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to design an observable task-like entity which would have the following properties:

- Reports its current state changes reactively
- Shares state and result events: new subscribers will also be notified if the change happens after they've subscribed
- Has a lifecycle (backed by CoroutineScope)
- Doesn't have suspend functions in the interface (because it has a lifecycle)

The very basic code is something like this:

```kotlin
class Worker {
  enum class State { Running, Idle }
  private val state = MutableStateFlow(State.Idle)
  private val results = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
  private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

  private suspend fun doWork(): String {
    println("doing work")
    return "Result of the work"
  }

  fun start() {
    scope.launch {
      state.value = State.Running

      results.emit(doWork())

      state.value = State.Idle
    }
  }

  fun state(): Flow<State> = state

  fun results(): Flow<String> = results
}
```

The problems with this arise when I want to "start the work after I'm subscribed". There's no clear way to do that. The simplest thing doesn't work (understandably):

```kotlin
fun main() {
  runBlocking {
    val worker = Worker()
    // subscriber 1
    launch {
      worker.results().collect { println("received result $it") }
    }
    worker.start()
    // subscriber 2 can also be created "later" and watch
    // for state()/result() changes
  }
}
```

This prints only "doing work" and never prints a result. I understand why this happens (because `collect` and `start` are in separate coroutines, not synchronized in any way).

Adding a `delay(300)` to coroutine inside `doWork` "fixes" things, results are printed, but I'd like this to work without artificial delays.

Another "solution" is to create a `SharedFlow` from `results()` and use its `onSubscription` to call `start()`, but that didn't work either last time I've tried.

My questions are:

- Can this be turned into something that works or is this design initially flawed?
- If it is flawed, can I take some other approach which would still hit all the goals I have specified in the beginning of the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your SharedFlow has no buffer set up, so it is emitting results to its (initially zero) current collectors and immediately forgetting them. The `MutableSharedFlow()` function has a `replay` parameter you can use to determine how many previous results it should store and replay to new collectors. You will need to decide what replay amount to use based on your use case for this class. For simply displaying latest results in a UI, a common choice is a replay of 1.

Depending on your use case, you may want to give your CoroutineScope a `SupervisorJob()` in its context so it isn't destroyed by any child job failing.

Side note, your `state()` and `results()` functions should be properties by Kotlin convention, since they do nothing but return references. Personally, I would also have them return read-only StateFlow/SharedFlow instead of just Flow to clarify that they are not cold.

Comment: 1. What if I want such a semantics where I do not replay results to subscribers? I.e. `results` behave event-like, not state-like. Will `extraBufferCapacity` be enough? Still unclear how to do this subscribe-before-start dance in this case...
2. Yep, "working prototype" has SupervisorJob, omitted here for simplicity
3. Same with state(), results(), I have them as properties actually

Comment: Do you mean you want a way to orchestrate your initial setup so your work only begins after initial collectors are already registered? But then future collectors won't get past events?  `extraBufferCapacity` doesn't replay anything. It just allows more events to be queued up before a call to `emit` will suspend to wait for the buffer to clear (i.e. get collected by all current collectors).

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to setup it so that a) collectors registered b) start() gets called c) collectors receive only emissions from "results" which happen after they registered, no replay. I'm struggling with setting up a) + b) in tandem in that order. This is actually based on an issue in a working code where I investigated why results are lost if "doWork" completes very quickly and are not lost if it takes some time.

Comment: This is a tricky problem. You have a race condition between the collection coroutine reaching the point where the collector is registered with the SharedFlow, and finishing the first piece of work. The problem is that there's no callback you can hook into when registering a collector to trigger when it has been registered.

Comment: I suppose your `start()` method could take a parameter for number of collectors the shared flow should have and then `while (results.subscriptionCount < expectedCount) yield()` before emitting. But then it would lock up if something caused one of those coroutines to cancel during that short time.

Comment: There's `onSubscription` in `SharedFlow`, but I guess it's not what would help here. I will play around `subscriptionCount` idea, thank you.

Comment: Update: looking at subscriptionCount helped me to start this in the required direction. For now I'm not handling the lock up you've mentioned, will think about it later. Thanks, @Tenfour04!